# spring cloud contract: user registration test

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I'm struggling with BCryptPasswordEncoder and groovy contract

I have a producer and a consumer service, the producer sends a message with user registration information (ie. user and password (encoded using BCryptPasswordEncoder(12)). The test is creating the message with the password encrypted, this is ok, but my questions are:
1. is it possible to encrypt the password in the contract? 
2. how? 
3. if possible how can I set BCryptPasswordEncoder(12)?

at the moment when running the test (mvn clean install) from the producer, the verification is failing since the encrypted password <> plain password defined in contract

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I have uploaded a sample to github https://github.com/dssantana/user-registration
If you run mvn clean install, you will find that at a certain point one of the tests fail with an error similar to:

> 2017-12-18 11:55:36.056  INFO [user-client,,,] 5236 --- [           main] .e.u.c.UserAccountRegistrationController : UserAccountRegistrationController - UserAccountRegister: 
>   AccountRegistration(firstName=Diego, lastName=Santana, email=dssantana@gmail.com, mobileNumber=0452621048, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, birthday=1979-10-16,
>   **password=$2a$12$jm3YACnf72P3wKCmPLRXwufeXJx5lzibwLz3DzhCXft.XKW2bK1RC**)
>   [ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.935 s <<< FAILURE! - in au.net.example.userclient.ContractVerifierTest
>   [ERROR] validate_shouldSendAnAccountRegistrationMessageWithSpecialCharactersUsername(au.net.example.userclient.ContractVerifierTest)  Time elapsed: 0.426 s  <<< ERROR!
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parsed JSON
>   [{"firstName":"Joe","lastName":"Doe","email":"joe.doe+test@gmail.com","mobileNumber":"0452621048","ipAddress":"127.0.0.1",
>   "birthday":"1979-10-16",**"password":"$2a$12$fZcEe6fUzmjHmItvsJ8MCOCOR.mnc2nbDqh/Ce1aYzUBRq5L8ywRm"}] 
>   doesn't match the JSON path [$[?(@.['password'] == 'Test01')**]]
>       at au.net.example.userclient.ContractVerifierTest.validate_shouldSendAnAccountRegistrationMessageWithSpecialCharactersUsername(ContractVerifierTest.java:49)
>   [ERROR] validate_shouldSendAnAccountRegistrationMessage(au.net.example.userclient.ContractVerifierTest)  Time elapsed: 0.323 s  <<< ERROR!
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parsed JSON
>   [{"firstName":"Diego","lastName":"Santana","email":"dssantana@gmail.com","mobileNumber":"0452621048","ipAddress":"127.0.0.1",
>   "birthday":"1979-10-16","password":"$2a$12$jm3YACnf72P3wKCmPLRXwufeXJx5lzibwLz3DzhCXft.XKW2bK1RC"}] doesn't match the JSON path [$[?(@.['password'] == 'Test01')]]
>       at au.net.example.userclient.ContractVerifierTest.validate_shouldSendAnAccountRegistrationMessage(ContractVerifierTest.java:33)

The encrypted password is Test01 and should match with the plain password in the contract test, however I'm not sure how to verify this, it's one way encryption and the way to verify is to encrypt and match the contract data with the test data.

Comment: Can you describe your current contract? Contract is a groovy DSL so if you ensure that you have the proper dependencies on both the consumer and the producer you can actually call the encoder.

Comment: the groovy DSL:
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    description "should produce a account registration message"
    label "account_registration_message"
    input {
        triggeredBy("triggerMessage()")
    }
    outputMessage {
        sentTo "account-registration"
        body([username: "joedoe@gmail.com", password: "Test01"])
    }
}

Comment: When generating the @Test is calling the rest controller that is generating and sending the message, this is working as expected, with username and encrypted password, but when verifying against the contract, it is failing due to the password in the contract is not encrypted, in case it is encrypted, the salt would be different and it won't match, how should I proceed? Thanks a million Marcin! I followed the Devoxx Poland video with Josh Long and you.

Comment: I think I figured it out, just importing import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder

then BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12) 

and in the body something like 

body([username: "joedoe@gmail.com", password: encoder.encode("Test01")])

I will try it and let you know

Comment: Yeah, that was the idea. I'm really interested if it will work. Ping me once you have some new info

Comment: I’ve been trying to make it work but the problem is that the salt changes randomly and you will never have the same password to verify, So the hash of the test and the hash of the contract will be always different, I’m really struggling with this... I try to use customisation however I’m always getting a different result, another solution would be to get the password from the test object after is set, that would be the solution but not sure if it is possible and how to do it

Comment: Can you upload the sample somewhere on github?

Comment: I have a workaround, it's not the best approach but at least I can continue with some work, basically I'm checking the profile before encrypting the password, if the profile contains "test" I will create the message with a plain text password, if not, it will be encrypted. The problem is that encoding the password it's changing in every execution and the test doesn't pass in the producer before creating the stub.

Comment: It will be hard to help you without a sample

Comment: Sorry mate, I was unable to do it until today, thanks for the support, the github repository is https://github.com/dssantana/user-registration and any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I've applied a PR https://github.com/dssantana/user-registration/pull/1/files and we can move the discussion there. After we come to some solution we can write it here.

Comment: Thanks for the support @MarcinGrzejszczak

Comment: you are a genius mate! thanks a million!!! Right on the spot, before looking at your change I was totally out of context, you open my mind on this! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As presented in this link https://github.com/dssantana/user-registration/pull/1/files what was added to the initial test setup is the `$( consumer("fixed value"), producer(regex(nonBlank())))` line to ensure that on the producer side, in the generated test we have some value of password